# What are the continuous functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ when $\mathbb{N}$ is given the coprime topology?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the topology generated by sets of the form $U_{a,b}=\mathbb{N} \ \cap \ \{an+b: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} $ where $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$.

What are the continuous functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ when $\mathbb{N}$ is given this topology and $\mathbb{R}$ has the Euclidean topology?

Some thoughts: if the range of such a continuous function were infinite, it would imply we could partition $\mathbb{N}$ into countably infinite many disjoint sets of the form $U_{a,b}$ as above, which somehow seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space (see [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000052)) is connected and countable, so its continuous image in $\Bbb R$ is also connected and countable hence a singleton. So all such maps are constant.